# Promoting the InterchangeID using a correlation set doesn't work - why not?

Tags: biztalk

I have a Direct to MessageBox send port publishing a message, for which I would like to have the InterchangeID promoted so that I can create a sequential convoy against the current batch of messages. I am using an initializing correlation set, declaring BTS.InterchangeID as the correlated property, and applying it to the Send action.

When I run the code, these messages cause routing errors. Looking at the routing failure report, I can see that the InterchangeID is present but is "Not Promoted".

Why in this particular case is the correlation set not promoting the property when this usually just works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you create your own message only context property that you can set using the `BTS.InterchangeID` value rather than trying to change the properties of an existing BizTalk one as it might have unintended consequences.

Comment: This is what I did in the end - but interestingly, promoting the `OperationName` property with the exact same method *did* work, so I conclude there must be something 'special' about the InterchangeID wired as it is into the messaging engine.